# Вернуть значение из функции Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Как вернуть результат выполнения функции?

```
    function getProxy(){
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM proxy WHERE count < 5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", function (err, result, fields) {
        return result;
    })
}
```

Comment: Нет ничего более постоянного, чем этот вопрос…

Answer (score 1):

предлагаю такой вариант:

```
(async () => {

    function getProxy() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM proxy", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                return resolve(result);
            })
        });
    }

    const result = await getProxy();
    console.log('result is:');
    console.log(result);

})()
```